# When writing the Caeser Cipher exercise, the input Secret Message should be outputted as Vhfuhw Phvvdjh but it is outputting as VhfuhwqPhvvdjh instead

Tags: python

My current code is looking like this:

```py
message = input("Message to be encrypted: ")
shift = int(input("Number to shift by: "))

def encrypt(message,shift):
    encryption = ""

    for i in range(len(message)):
        char = message[i]
 
        if (char.isupper()):
            encryption += chr((ord(char) + shift-65) % 26 + 65) 

 
        else:
            encryption += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
 
    return encryption

print("Encrypted Text:",encrypt(message,shift))
```

And I am not too sure on my whitespace character is coming out as q instead of a normal " " in a string.  This is my first few weeks of coding so I apologize if I have overlooked a simple mistake.

Comment: What is your input for message?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
For `char = " "`, is `char.isupper()` `True`? What gets appended to `encryption` in this case? What do you want to add instead?

Comment: @Nic The input is `message = "Secret Message" ` and `shift = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expected result, you should add this conditional before the others:

```
if char == " ":
    encryption += " "
    continue
```

You are not getting the desired output because when you got a space in the input string and passes to the `char` variable, the space is not a upper letter so your code goes right in the `else` statement. Although it works for letters it won't work for other special characters. So, as described in the title of your question, if you wish to maintain the space between the words, you simply add the space in your encrypted sentence.

However, my first suggestion will work only for the spaces. If you wish to mantain other special characters (i.e. %, $, #, *, etc) you should use:

```
if char.isalnum() == False:
    encryption += char
    continue
```